# How to pass this array in mongoose to a callback 'meme.find({}, (err, meme) => { const memes = meme.map(m => m); });'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got an assignment to pass the array in the following mongoose query to a callback but as a beginner, I don't have an idea on how to do it properly.

```
meme.find({}, (err, meme) => {
  const memes = meme.map(m => m);
  // Use the array, pass it to a service, or pass to a callback
});
```

`const memes = meme.map(m => m);` is the array in the question.

Please, can someone shed some light on how I can pass it to a callback?

Thanks.

Comment: btw, why do you map the same array? you could `slice` it (for primitive values).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `memes = meme.slice()`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside an anonymous function and pass that array. And then use that array wherever you want in it

```
(function (memes){
meme.find({}, (err, meme) => {

  // You can access memes array here
});
}(memes));
```